# Como passar um valor de um método para outro método dentro da mesma classe ? C#

Tags: c#

Gostaria de passar a variável tot que está em CadastroDespesas em float para o método MostrarDespesas. Alguém pode me ajudar ??

```
class Ex4
{
    List<String> descricaodespesas = new List<string>();
    List<float> valordespesas = new List<float>();
    List<String> descricaoreceitas = new List<string>();
    List<float> valorreceitas = new List<float>();

    public void CadastroDespesas()
    {
        string descricao;
        float valor;
        float soma = 0,tot;
        Console.Write("Informe o valor: ");
        valor = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        valordespesas.Add(valor);
        Console.WriteLine("Informe uma descrição:");
        descricao = (Console.ReadLine());
        descricaodespesas.Add(descricao);
        foreach (float som in valordespesas)
        {
            soma += valor;
        }
        tot = soma;
    }

    public void MostrarDespesas()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("------Despesas Informadas------");
        Console.WriteLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < descricaodespesas.Count; i++)
        {
            string desc = descricaodespesas.ElementAt(i);
            float valor = valordespesas.ElementAt(i);
            Console.Write("Descrição: "); Console.WriteLine(desc);
            Console.Write("Valor: "); Console.WriteLine(valor);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: coloque ela fora do método no escopo geral da classe ai todos os métodos terão acesso.

Comment: declara fora, igual ao que fez para o descricaodespesas

Comment: resolveu seu problema?

Comment: Sim. Obrigado a Todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Veja: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3117)

Answer (score 0):

Existem algumas maneiras de fazer isso. Vou apresentar duas:

### Primeira solução:

```
 public void MostrarDespesas(float tot)
 {
     // Agora você tem acesso ao valor que está no tot, faça o que quiser com ele
     Console.WriteLine("------Despesas Informadas------");
     Console.WriteLine();
     for(int i = 0; i < descricaodespesas.Count; i++)
     {
         string desc = descricaodespesas.ElementAt(i);
         float valor = valordespesas.ElementAt(i);
         Console.Write("Descrição: "); Console.WriteLine(desc);
         Console.Write("Valor: "); Console.WriteLine(valor);
     }
     Console.ReadLine();
}
```

A partir de agora, na hora que quiser chamar o método `MostrarDespesas(float tot)`, terá que informar um valor float por parâmetro. Utilizei como exemplo a sua váriavel tot:

```
tot = 100;

MostrarDespesas(tot);
```

### Segunda solução:

Ou utilizando a ideia dada pelo @Virgilio, declare a variável `tot` como uma variável de classe, podendo utilizá-la em qualquer lugar da sua classe:

```
class Ex4
{
    List<String> descricaodespesas = new List<string>();
    List<float> valordespesas = new List<float>();
    List<String> descricaoreceitas = new List<string>();
    List<float> valorreceitas = new List<float>();
    float _tot; // Variável tot declarada como variável de classe
}
```

Não é mais necessário declarar a `tot` aqui pois já foi declarada no topo da classe (código acima):

```
public void CadastroDespesas()
{
    string descricao;
    float valor;
    float soma = 0; // Declaração removida 'tot''
    Console.Write("Informe o valor: ");
    valor = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
    valordespesas.Add(valor);
    Console.WriteLine("Informe uma descrição:");
    descricao = (Console.ReadLine());
    descricaodespesas.Add(descricao);
    foreach (float som in valordespesas)
    {
        soma += valor;
    }

    // Utilize a variável _tot
    _tot = soma;
}
```

A partir de agora, você consegue acessar a variável `_tot` de qualquer lugar da sua classe, contento o valor da soma.

Comment: Show de bola galera, agradeço a todos pela ajuda.

Comment: Sem problemas! Se a resposta te ajudou, marque ela como a correta para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida!

Answer (score 0):

Você esta fazendo algumas coisas desnecessárias no seu método.

```
public void CadastroDespesas()
{
    string descricao;
    float valor;
    float soma = 0,tot;
    Console.Write("Informe o valor: ");
    valor = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
    valordespesas.Add(valor);
    Console.WriteLine("Informe uma descrição:");
    descricao = (Console.ReadLine());
    descricaodespesas.Add(descricao);
    foreach (float som in valordespesas)
    {
        soma += valor;
    }
    tot = soma;
}
```

Vamos simplificar para;

```
public void CadastroDespesas()
{
    string descricao;
    float valor;
    Console.Write("Informe o valor: ");
    valor = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
    valordespesas.Add(valor);
    Console.WriteLine("Informe uma descrição:");
    descricao = (Console.ReadLine());
    descricaodespesas.Add(descricao);   
}
```

E no seu outro método basta acessar sua lista para recuperar os valores usando o [Sum()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298381(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
   public void MostrarDespesas()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("------Despesas Informadas------");
        Console.WriteLine();
        for(int i = 0; i < descricaodespesas.Count; i++)
        {
            string desc = descricaodespesas.ElementAt(i);
            float valor = valordespesas.ElementAt(i);
            Console.Write("Descrição: "); Console.WriteLine(desc);
            Console.Write("Valor: "); Console.WriteLine(valor);
        }

// Basta usar o Sum do linq na sua lista para recuperar o valor total
        var tot = valordespesas.Sum();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode retornar o valor de `tot` de dentro da função `CadastroDespesas` trocando `void` pelo tipo de variávell que você quer retornar, no seu caso é um `float`, sua função teria esse cabeçalho:

```
public float CadastroDespesa(){

}
```

E no fim dela você retorna `tot`:

```
return tot;
```

Agora você precisa alterar o método `MostrarDespesas` pedindo um float para ser exibido:

```
 public void MostrarDespesas(float valorTotalDespesas)
 {
 }
```

O mais correto é **primeiro** você receber o valor de `CadastroDespesa` e depois chamar `MostrarDespesas` passando o valor recebido:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Ex4 DespesaManager = new Ex4();
            float tot = DespesaManager.CadastroDespesa();
            DespesaManager.MostrarDespesas(tot);
        }
    }
}
```

Esse é o modo como você utilizaria as alterações. O seu código em sí fica assim:

```
class Ex4
{
    List<String> descricaodespesas = new List<string>();
    List<float> valordespesas = new List<float>();
    List<String> descricaoreceitas = new List<string>();
    List<float> valorreceitas = new List<float>();

    public float CadastroDespesas()
    {
        string descricao;
        float valor;
        float soma = 0,tot;
        Console.Write("Informe o valor: ");
        valor = Convert.ToSingle(Console.ReadLine());
        valordespesas.Add(valor);
        Console.WriteLine("Informe uma descrição:");
        descricao = (Console.ReadLine());
        descricaodespesas.Add(descricao);
        foreach (float som in valordespesas)
        {
            soma += valor;
        }
        tot = soma;
        return tot;
    }

    public void MostrarDespesas(float valorTotalDespesas)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("------Despesas Informadas------");
         Console.WriteLine();
         for(int i = 0; i < descricaodespesas.Count; i++)
         {
             string desc = descricaodespesas.ElementAt(i);
             float valor = valordespesas.ElementAt(i);
             Console.Write("Descrição: "); Console.WriteLine(desc);
             Console.Write("Valor: "); Console.WriteLine(valor);
          }
          Console.WriteLine("Valor total: "); 
          Console.WriteLine(valorTotalDespesas);
          Console.ReadLine();
     }
```

Essa é a sua maneira de fazer, porém eu acho que seria mais interessante você utilizar a própria lista `valordespesas` para somar, você pode utilizar o LINQ assim:

```
valordespesas.Sum();
```

Sendo assim você não precisaria retornar nada nas suas funções, `MostrarDespesas` fica assim:

```
    public void MostrarDespesas()
    {
         Console.WriteLine("------Despesas Informadas------");
         Console.WriteLine();
         for(int i = 0; i < descricaodespesas.Count; i++)
         {
             string desc = descricaodespesas.ElementAt(i);
             float valor = valordespesas.ElementAt(i);
             Console.Write("Descrição: "); Console.WriteLine(desc);
             Console.Write("Valor: "); Console.WriteLine(valor);
          }
          Console.WriteLine("Valor total: "); 
          Console.WriteLine(valordespesas.Sum());
          Console.ReadLine();
     }
```

Comment: Não consigo marcar as respostas como corretas, talvez seja pq fiz a pergunta como visitante, porém já solucionou meu problema, agradeço a todos pela ajuda. (Criei uma conta agora mas ele não reconhece essa pergunta como minha.)